# How to use Jacobian on chain rule

Tags: matrices, products, jacobian

I have an affine layer in a neural network doing a matrix multiplication of two metrics, $X \; @ \; W^{T}$ (@ is matmul in Python notation) and I try to calculate the $\frac {\partial L}{ \partial W^T}$ using the **chain rule** and **Jacobian**.

As explained in [Product of Jacobians and chain Rule](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2917459/product-of-jacobians-and-chain-rule/2917464#2917464), I need to apply the Jacobian $J(f \circ g) = JfJg \quad$, which I believed the same with $\quad J(f \circ g) = Jf \; @ \; Jg$. However, the shape of the matrices do not match to produce the shape `(3,2)` of $\frac {\partial L}{\partial W^T}$

Please help understand what is wrong.

[image]

[image]

---

Please help to understand how to calculate $Jg(W^T) = \frac {\partial Y}{\partial W^T}:
    \begin{bmatrix}
        \begin{matrix}
            \frac{\partial Y}{\partial w_{(m=0,d=0)}} \\
            \frac{\partial Y}{\partial w_{(m=0,d=1)}} \\
            \frac{\partial Y}{\partial w_{(m=0,d=2)}} 
        \end{matrix} 
        &
        \begin{matrix}
            \frac{\partial Y}{\partial w_{(m=1,d=0)}} \\
            \frac{\partial Y}{\partial w_{(m=1,d=1)}} \\
            \frac{\partial Y}{\partial w_{(m=1,d=2)}} 
        \end{matrix}
    \end{bmatrix}
$.

$ \frac{\partial Y}{\partial w_{(m,d)}}$ has the same shape `(2,)` with `Y`, because $w_{(m,d)}$ is scalar. Then it will be like below which has a strange structure.

I believe I misunderstood something and appreciate an advice on what I am missing.

[image]